# staff and faculty name and annual salary in descending order

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

In my program did faculty details like name birth date, status.It's just print for faculty. 
I got output like this:

```
John was born on Sun Jan 03 00:00:00 MST 1971: fulltime
```

Then I want to prints the name and annual salary of each Staff member and Faculty and Salary must be descending order.
I got output like this:

```
John was born on Sun Jan 03 00:00:00 MST 1971: fulltime
[Barry was born on Tue Jan 02 00:00:00 MST 1973: part-time, Andy was born on Wed Nov 12 00:00:00 MST 1980: full-time,  
 Name: Edith  Annual Salary : 7416.666666666666,  
 Name: Don  Annual Salary : 5866.666666666667,  
 Name: Cathy  Annual Salary : 2900.0]
```

but i just got staff name and annual salary. I want to print faculty name and annual salary as well.I don't know where Am I wrong?
How can I do that?

Person Class:

```
public abstract class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    protected String firstName;
    protected java.util.Date birthdate;

    public Person(String firstName, java.util.Date birthdate) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.birthdate = birthdate;
    }

    public java.util.Date getBirthdate() {
        return birthdate;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setBirthdate(java.util.Date birthdate) {
        this.birthdate = birthdate;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return " \n" + " Name: " + getName()+ " " + " Annual Salary : " + getSalary();
    }

    public abstract Double getSalary();

    public int compareTo(Person o) {
         Person per =(Person)o;

            if (this.getSalary() > per.getSalary()){
                return -1;
            }else if (this.getSalary() < per.getSalary()){
                return 1;
            }else
                return 0;

  }

}
```

Faculty class:

```
public class Faculty extends Person{

    private double monthlySalary;
    private String status;
    public Faculty(String firstName, Date birthdate, double salaryln, String statusln) {
        super(firstName, birthdate);

        this.monthlySalary = salaryln;
        this.status = statusln;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

@Override

    public Double getSalary() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        double fsalary = monthlySalary*9.0;
        return fsalary;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public double getMonthlySalary() {
        return monthlySalary;
    }

    public void setMonthlySalary(double monthlySalary) {
        this.monthlySalary = monthlySalary;
    }

     public String toString(){
            return getName() + " was born on " + birthdate +  ": " + getStatus();
        }

}
```

Staff Class:

```
public class Staff extends Person{

    private double annualSalary;
    private double experience;

    public Staff(String firstName, Date birthdate, double salaryln, double experienceln) {
        super(firstName, birthdate);
        this.annualSalary = salaryln;
        this.experience = experienceln;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Double getSalary() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        double staffSalary = annualSalary + annualSalary*(30.0-experience)/60.0;
        return staffSalary;
    }

    public double getAnnualSalary() {
        return annualSalary;
    }

    public void setAnnualSalary(double annualSalary) {
        this.annualSalary = annualSalary;
    }

    public double getExperience() {
        return experience;
    }

    public void setExperience(int experience) {
        this.experience = experience;
    }

}
```

PersonTest Class:

```
public class PersonTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy";
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
            Date date = format.parse("01/03/1971");
            Faculty faculty = new Faculty("John", date, 2000, "fulltime"); 
            System.out.println(faculty);



        Person[] ps = new Person[5];

        ps[0] = new Staff("Cathy", format.parse("8/19/1968"), 2000.0, 3.0);
        ps[1] = new Staff("Don", format.parse("4/17/1969"), 4000.0, 2.0);
        ps[2] = new Staff("Edith", format.parse("10/28/1979"), 5000.0, 1.0);
        ps[3] = new Faculty("Andy", format.parse("11/12/1980"), 4000.0, "full-time");
        ps[4] = new Faculty("Barry", format.parse("1/2/1973"), 6000.0, "part-time");




        Arrays.sort(ps);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ps) );
        System.out.println();

    }

}
```

Comment: Create a custom comparator to do this.

Comment: @ifly6 I need to use Comparable with comparator?

Comment: Put them all into a `List` (or some other sortable Collection or array) and then sort it with a `Comparator` that defines how the order ought be. You could create a custom comparator now with Java 8 that says something along the lines of `Comparator.comparing(x -> x.variable())` so long as `x.variable()` returns something that can be sorted in natural order. After that, you can then use `comparator.thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(x -> x.num()));` to continue going down.

Comment: Never mind, ignore that, I was interpreting the question incorrectly. This shouldn't be a sorting question.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Faculty` class, you override `toString()` like so:

```
// There should be a @Override here.
public String toString(){
    return getName() + " was born on " + birthdate +  ": " + getStatus();
}
```

This means that when you print the array, which invokes `Faculty::toString`, it prints what you defined as the `String` representation of the `Faculty` object, which is the name with some birth date and status.

If you want to print it using the `Person` definition, you should stop overriding the `toString` method and therefore have `Faculty` default to the superclass's `toString` method (alternatively, change the name of `Faculty::toString` to something different) or cast `Faculty` to `Person` such that you can access `Person::toString` and print using that method instead of the overriden version.

Also, if your `Person::compareTo` is pretty much going to be simple integer comparison, you could just use: `return Integer.compare(this.getSalary(), o.getSalary())`.

If you find my answer useful, please accept it!

Comment: How do I stop overriding the toString method ?

Comment: you delete it from the faculty class